# How to setup Nagios Alerts for Apache Airflow Dags

Tags: airflow, nagios

Is it possible to setup Nagios alerts for airflow dags?
In case the dag is failed, I need to alert the respective groups.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an "on_failure_callback" to any task which will call an arbitrary failure handling function.  In that function you can then send an error call to Nagios.

For example:

```
dag = DAG(dag_id="failure_handling",
          schedule_interval='@daily')

def handle_failure(context):
    # first get useful fields to send to nagios/elsewhere
    dag_id = context['dag'].dag_id
    ds = context['ds']
    task_id = context['ti'].task_id
    # instead of printing these out - you can send these to somewhere else
    logging.info("dag_id={}, ds={}, task_id={}".format(dag_id, ds, task_id))

def task_that_fails(**kwargs):
    raise Exception("failing test")

task_to_fail = PythonOperator(
    task_id='python_task_to_fail',
    python_callable=task_that_fails,
    provide_context=True,
    on_failure_callback=handle_failure,
    dag=dag)
```

If you run a test on this:
    airflow test failure_handling task_to_fail 2018-08-10

You get the following in your log output:
    INFO - dag_id=failure_handling, ds=2018-08-10, task_id=task_to_fail